# PushViewController in fullscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I'd like to know if it's possible to push a `ViewController` of the `NavigationController` in full screen without tabbar and navigation bar. My problem is as follow:

My app has a `NavigationController` embedded in a `TabBarController`. In the `NavController` I show a `FirstVC` with a button to navigate to another VC. Right now I do a modal presentation to show the `SecondVC`. But in this `SecondVC` I have a tableview where a button returns a `ThirdVC`. This `ThirdVC` needs to have the navigationbar and tabbar of the `FirstVC`. Maybe I need to show the `SecondVC` with a push on the `NavigationController` of the first but it seems that I can't reproduce my full screen animation ...

To make it simple:

```
FirstVC ===> SecondVC (modal presentation) ====> ThirdVC (modal presentation):
```

This is my app at this time without navbar or tabbar on the `ThirdVC`.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

The modal presentation to the `SecondVC` is like that:

```
- (IBAction)detailButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    SecondVC *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

From the `SecondVC` to the `ThirdVC` I use again presentViewController because I can't use pushViewController in modal. The result is predictable: I don't have a navigation bar or a tabbar.

I tried different things like the one below or addChildView as subview to my `FirstVC`:

```
- (IBAction)detailButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    SecondVC *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];
    UINavigationController *childNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    childNavigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:childNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

and in the `SecondVC`

```
- (IBAction)changeButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    ThirdVC *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThirdVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
 }
```

I can't access my tabbar or navigation bar in the `ThirdVC` either...

Comment: can you please show your code.

Comment: @Kiritan if you want to navigation bar than you have to push. modal not work.

Comment: @NimitParekh thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kiritan Are you want to access the `UITabBarController` in `SecondVC` or not?

Comment: @NimitParekh No I don't want to acces the TabBarController in the SecondVC. Only in the ThirdVC.

Comment: if possible can you please send me your sample code I need to do more things I will do and send revert back to you

Comment: @NimitParekh I recreate a simple example which has the same problem. How can I send it to you ?

Comment: upload on google drive and give me URL

Comment: @NimitParekh I send it to your email address mentioned in your profile.

Comment: Ok Fine I will get back you very soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do in your is I added following code improvement.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                             bundle: nil];
    SecondViewController *vc = (SecondViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                          instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SecondVC"];
    vc.delegate = self;

    [[APP_DELEGATE window] addSubview:vc.view];
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
}
```

Main line of code is `addchildViewController`.

[Here You can download the sample code of yours.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxVigM97JuzCbVJfd0g5eTR4MkU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for your help !